# Distance queries to reconstruct an unknown graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a finite, simple, connected, undirected graph on $n$ vertices.
Suppose your goal is to determine $G$ uniquely
via queries.
Each query choses a $v_i$, and returns the shortest distances (number of edges)
from $v_i$ to each other $v_j$, $j \neq i$.
So, for a $4$-vertex graph, a $v_1$ query might return this
(indices on 1st row, distances on 2nd row):
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

---

[image: G]

---

This data is compatible with graphs (a), (b), (c), (d) above,
but not (e), because the distance from $v_1$ to $v_4$ should
be $2$, not $1$.
If now we query distances from $v_2$, and receive this information,
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
then only (a) and (c) are compatible. One more query seems
necessary to pin down which.

Under the scenario where the user chooses each query after
reviewing the results of the previous queries:

> ***Q1***. Are there classes of graphs on $n$ vertices that require $n$ queries
>   to pin down their structure?

I believe if one knows the complete distance matrix, then 
the adjacency matrix is determined, and so
$G$ is determined.

> ***Q2***. Can sub-linear queries suffice for (a) some
>   natural class of graphs (e.g, trees?), or (b) for some model of random graphs (e.g., Erdős-Rényi)?

Comment: You need n-1 queries (or some not so unlucky guessing) to distinguish between the complete graph and the complete graph minus an edge.  I think n guesses would yield redundant information.  Gerhard "There's An App For That" Paseman, 2019.12.21.

Comment: $n-1$ queries are enough: After querying the first $n-1$ vertices, we know which vertices among the first $n-1$ vertices are adjacent to the $n$th vertex, so the graph is complete determined.

Comment: Let $G$ be a graph where $x$ and $y$ have the same set of neighbours. Let $H_x$ and $H_y$ be new graphs: $V(H_x)=V(G) \cup a$, and $E(H_x)=E(G) \cup (x,a)$, similarly for $V(H_y)$. Then one cannot tell $H_x$ from $H_y$ before querying $x$, $y$ or $a$.

Comment: I added "connected." And added trees as a possible interesting class, because the distance matrix of a tree has special properties.

Comment: For trees,  note the "claw"-gulation: for each v, add u and w connected to v and add t connected to one of u or w. You need to query each claw (one of t,u, or w) to find its orientation, so n/4 queries minimum for the clawgulation of a tree.  Gerhard "Has Found Favorite Mathematical Terminology" Paseman, 2019.12.22.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: "to find its orientation": Perhaps there are two versions of what constitutes "determining the graph." One up to isomorphism; another requiring exact labeling.

Comment: If you don't care which of u and w is adjacent to t, then it might help. However, -gulation seems powerful enough to tackle isomorphism also: we know t is distance two from v, but we don't know without querying u or w if a path from v to t goes through one of those.  Gerhard "May Still Need Maps App" Paseman, 2019.12.22.

Answer (score 1):

This is an intriguing question.  From one query, one can establish a lot of nonedges: if two vertices differ in distance from a third by two or more, these two vertices are not neighbors.  So it would seem from taking queries from a few "remote" vertices, one could determine a lot of nonedges and come close to determining the graph. However, "triangulating" a graph (in the sense I am about to introduce), means one can't triangulate a graph with a few distance observations in the sense Joseph asks. In particular, one needs at least n/3 queries.

Here is my sense of triangulation, which should work for any base graph, but start with a path for example of m vertices. We will make a graph of n=3m vertices by adding triangles to the original graph: for each vertex v, add a vertex u and w, and the only new edges are the triangle connecting u,v, and w; u and w connect to nothing else in the construction.

For each pair of u and w, you have to query one of them to see if there is an edge between them. All other queries "have to go through v", and will not be able to determine if u and w have such an edge. Thus you need n/3 queries to cover the triangles.  By combining this idea with the comment, you can (K_d)-gulate a graph to force a large fraction of vertices to be queried to determine the graph.  Of course, you can make it even more interesting by removing an edge from each K_d pendant.

Gerhard "Graph Zoo Has New Member" Paseman, 2019.12.21.

Comment: I'll leave the formal details to others. However, the "-gulation" construction seems to allow modifications to cover both parts of Joseph's Q2, and that graphs which are triangulable in Joseph's sense may be only those which have few cycles, and those cycles being large.  Gerhard "Has Been Around The Block" Paseman, 2019.12.21.